# Can´t set up Wifi, says it´s using alternate drivers(?)

Tags: drivers, wireless, additional-drivers

I just installed the latest version of amd64 Ubuntu. Spent hours trying to get the wifi card up and running and I just can´t, it says that the card is using "alternate drivers", and can´t find any solution online. Any idea of what can I do to fix it? I´m just starting using linux, so I´m a basic rookie rn.
(Photos for hardware specifications)

[image: Wifi card details]

[image: What it says when I try to update the drivers]

Comment: What result from terminal for `mokutil --sb-state`

Answer (score 0):

So, at the end I just disabled Secure Boot and that was it. Maybe I´ts basic as hell, but it was my first Linux installation. So, if any future rookies see this, just get to your bios boot options and disable secure boot.